# Ruby webservices - xmlparser issue

Tags: ruby, soap, soap4r

After trying to set up webservice setup using Ruby I encountered problems with xmlparser. As I see - it is common problem (e.g. [Ruby soap4r wsdl2ruby.rb errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754965/ruby-soap4r-wsdl2ruby-rb-errors)), but it's solution, however simple, isn't successful to me.

I'm trying to run code taken from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_services.htm with little correction (signal string had no enclosing apostrophe). I installed firstly soap4r using

```
$ gem install soap4r --include-dependencies
```

and fixed xmlparser.rb:66 to

```
  c.to_s.downcase == name
```

code:

```
require "soap/rpc/standaloneserver"

begin
   class MyServer < SOAP::RPC::StandaloneServer

      # Expose our services
      def initialize(*args)
         add_method(self, 'add', 'a', 'b')
         add_method(self, 'div', 'a', 'b')
      end

      # Handler methods
      def add(a, b)
         return a + b
      end
      def div(a, b) 
         return a / b 
      end
  end
  server = MyServer.new("MyServer", 
            'urn:ruby:calculation', 'localhost', 8080)
  trap('INT'){
     server.shutdown
  }
  server.start
rescue => err
  puts err.message
end
```

this unfortunately still isn't working. It throws me an error:

```
undefined method `add_rpc_operation' for nil:NilClass
```

after invoking add_method(self, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering myself: this snippet is incomplete. There is lack for super constructor call. Adding:

```
super(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3])
```

will make it all work